# In Word, formatting disappears when italics shortcut is pressed while cursor is within a word

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, text-formatting

I'm sure there's an easy solution to this one, but it's such a specific situation that it's hard to Google for it. What happens is this: In Word, I press ctrl-I. I type a word. I press ctrl-I again, because the word is in parentheses so I need to put a non-italic closing bracket right after it; the italics formatting vanishes. What I want is this: (*word*), what I get is this: (word).
Is there a way in Word to just switch off the styled input, without removing the style from the previous word? In fact, why is that option set as a default at all? It's very annoying.

Comment: Works fine for me - might want to post your Version of Office and read the documentation microsoft provides

Comment: Okay, I've just been playing with it and it's a very specific case - it's if there's no space between the word I am editing and the following word. So it will occur in this situation: (_italic_Next sentence. Pressing ctrl-I there will render the italic-styled word non-italic. I suppose I'll just have to type a space and then pedal back a character before I close the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting bored while changing `style` then you can do 1 thing,
first write that word completely and then double-click on that word which you want `ITALIC` and now press `CTRL+I`, this will change `style` of only selected word nor `braces` also.

Ex. It will output,

(***word***)

Comment: True, but when I'm doing intensive, fiddly work, I don't like using the mouse at all. It would be nice if Word behaved itself in all cases - this case, as it turns out, is only if there's a non-styled word directly following the word I'm editing, with no intervening space - then Word will override my styling.

Comment: yes you are true :) , thanx, I will do hard work for this

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is an old thread, but I believe I have the answer:

Go to **File | Options | Advanced**.  Under Editing options, UNCHECK the box for "When selecting, automatically select entire word."  This should resolve the issue.

(This is in Word 2010 by the way.)